# Mouse button click not working during Ubuntu 20.04 LTS dual boot installation

Tags: dual-boot, mouse

My machine configuration:

iBUYPOWER - Gaming Desktop - Intel Core i7-9700K - 16GB Memory - NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER - 1TB HDD + 480GB SSD

I am using a logitech MK520 wireless keyboard and  mouse combo. The mouse has two buttons, a scroll button, two buttons on the side (for scrolling webbrowser history), and one more button on top (I don't know what it is used for).

The mouse and keyboards work fine in Windows 10. I am trying to do a dual boot installation by installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The machine boots into Ubuntu (the iso is on a bootable flash drive). Then Ubuntu can detect both the keyboard and mouse. However, the mouse clicks don't work. I am able to use keyboard enter, right, left arrows to navigate. Also I used CTR+ALT+T for opening a bash shell and was able to shutdown using Shutdown -r now command.

Is there an advice on how to make the mouse clicks work?

Comment: I'm also currently experimenting this rather unfortunate issue with a desktrop and a Logitech G403 mouse, with a recent 20.04 usb install drive.

Answer (score -2):

I had this during my install. The issue was that I had two monitors and the mouse pointer was actually on the opposite monitor that was displayed. I was able to move the mouse over and guess what fields it was on as the pointer changed.